# Questions of a positive summable sequence about some conditions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing positive real summable sequence, that is, $a_n > 0$ and $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n < \infty$.

Without loss of generality, we always assume $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n = 1$.

Let $s_n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{i = 2^n}^{\infty} a_i$.

Let $\delta$ be a given positive real number and $0 < \delta <1$, then my questions are,

1. Is there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying $s_{n+1}^{1-\delta} \leq s_n$ for all $n$ but not satisfying $a_{n}^{1-\delta} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} a_i$ for some $n$?
2. Is there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying  $a_{n}^{1-\delta} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} a_i$ for all $n$ but not satisfying $s_{n+1}^{1-\delta} \leq s_n$ for some $n$?
3. Is there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfying  $a_{n}^{1-\delta} \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} a_i$ and $s_{n+1}^{1-\delta} \leq s_n$ for all $n$?